# Apache rewrite slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to create rewrite rule(s) that catches couple of urls and redirects them depending if the content is available on the first location. If not, then call a url on the application so that it will regenerate it (and next time we can access it from the hard drive).

Let me insert the code here, so it will be easier to understand:

```
# I need to catch more than one page (and it has to work with and without the trailing slash!)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(/?|/page1/?|/page2/subpage/?)$ [NC]
# If the content exists
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" -f
# Go to the exported folder and try to serve the page from there
# The first slash problem is here: if I have trailing slash, it will not work, because it will try to go here: /var/www/contentstatic/export/sites/default/$1//index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/contentstatic/export/sites/default/$1/index.html
# Otherwise run this rule (regenerate the file)
# This has to be changed (to something), because this will catch anything, but I need only the paths I defined earlier: ^(/?|/page1/?|/page2/subpage/?)$ <- Also I have to make sure the that last trailing slash is not there
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://application1:8080/export/sites/default/$1/index.html  [P]
# At the bottom of the VirtualHost, there is another application that catches all the requests by default, so that's why I shouldn't use the "^(.*)$" in the previous RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://application2:8080/$1  [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://application2:8080/
```

The problems I have here:

1. This has to work with and without the trailing slash
2. I have to specify exactly what URLs to be served up from the /var/www/ folder or from the /export/sites/default folder, because if I don't do that the default application tries that, but it will fail

I also tried to remove the trailing slash from the url if it is there (in the first RewriteRule), but this rule:

```
[^/](.*)[^/]
```

changed the url from this: /page2/ to this: age2, so it removed the slashes and the first and last character.

Is it possible to use the same "^(/?|/page1/?|/page2/subpage/?)$" paths in the 3rd and 4th RewriteRule without repeating them?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the trailing slash by changing the regex to `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ ...` Don't understand the rest of your question. The third rule will never be executed, second rule will always match anything.

Comment: Thanks, I added new comment to the code (for the second rewriterule), so maybe it will be easier to understand. I tried your suggestion: RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /var/www/contentstatic/export/sites/default/$1/index.html but it doesn't apply the rule to the /page1/ url (I checked it in the log file).

Comment: You can't rewrite to a file on disk, rewrites apply to URLs, so any rule that includes `/var/www/....` is just wrong. I think you should rewrite the question to explain what you're trying to do, rather than what to fix. I suspect you probably want `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in your first `RewriteCond`